# Java regex delete every char after specific char line by line

Tags: java, regex

I have textfile with lines like:

```
stackoverflow (200) stack over flow
stack over flow (150) over flow 
stack (15) 
stackoverflow (50) something
```

and I need to delete everything after () to get

```
stackoverflow (200)
stack over flow (150)
stack (15)
stackoverflow (50)
```

I tried with

```
 String string = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("file.txt")));

  String result = string.split("\\)")[0];
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Learning Regular Expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)

Comment: *"but it doesn't work"* what does it mean?

Comment: you can simply use `indexof` along with`substring`

Comment: You need to use `replaceAll` and capturing groups :)

Comment: @TimothyTruckle
it works only if I have one line string, but I have file with 5k lines

Comment: @Skillzone - Then read the file line by line using `Files.readAllLines()` and then apply the regex to *each line*. I would suggest using `replaceAll` instead of `split`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following regex will do the trick. You replace all string of the form `(200) to be removed \n` with `(200)` (that is `$1`)

`s.replaceAll("(\\(.*\\)).*\\n?", "$1\n")`